# Collider.Enabled error: true and then false loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make my animated enemy (child object) disable its collider once enemieDeath == true. I wrote a debug.log and it says "Collider. Enabled = true, Collider. Enabled = false, it does this in an endless loop after my player collides with the enemie child (which has animation).

This is the script I am using.

**EnemieMove Script**

//References PlayerController Script

```
            if (playerControllerScript.enemieDeath == true)
        {
            goblinCollider.enabled = !goblinCollider.enabled;
            enemieAnimator.SetBool("IsDead", true);
            Debug.Log("Collider.enabled = " + goblinCollider.enabled);
        }
    }
```

**Player Controller Script**

```
        void FixedUpdate()
        {

         int layerMask = 1 << 8;
         int layerMaskCollectable = 1 << 9;
         RaycastHit hit;

         if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.down), out hit, 1.5f, layerMask))
        {
           Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.down) * hit.distance, Color.yellow);
           Debug.Log("Did Hit");
           enemieDeath = true;
           //Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject); 
           playerRb.AddForce(Vector3.up * bounceForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
           gameManager.UpdateScore(20);
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post where exactly the first code block is executed but from the behavior I can just guess that it is within `Update` or `FixedUpdate` (or anything else that is called repeatedly).

So as soon as you set the `playerControllerScript.enemieDeath` to `true` it will be executed over and over again everytime toggling the enabled value.

A quick fix would be to rather check and set

```c#
if (playerControllerScript.enemieDeath && goblinCollider.enabled)
{
    goblinCollider.enabled = false;
    enemieAnimator.SetBool("IsDead", true);
    Debug.Log("Collider.enabled = " + goblinCollider.enabled);
}
```

---

As a more general fix: Stop poll checking bool flags! Rather make your code event driven and disabled the collider etc **ONCE** when the event is actually occuring.

have e.g.

```c#
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event Action OnEnemyDied;

    private void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        ...

        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.down), out hit, 1.5f, layerMask))
        {
           ...

           OnEnemyDied?.Invoke();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

This way you can simply register a callback that will be executed only when this event is invoked like e.g.

```c#
public class EnemyMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private PlayerController playerControllerScript;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        playerControllerScript.OnEnemyDied += OnEnemyDied;
    }

    private void OnEnemyDied ()
    {
        if(golblinCollider.enabled)
        {
            goblinCollider.enabled = false;
            enemieAnimator.SetBool("IsDead", true);
            Debug.Log("Collider.enabled = " + goblinCollider.enabled);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```